# Parallel Python - create objects into another class in parallel execution

Tags: python, class, parallel-processing, parameter-passing

I'm trying to do something pretty simple with Parallel Python. I would like to be able to create an object from a class I've created inside another method from a class use to do a job in parallel. 
Here is a basic example of what I would like to make it work :

```
import pp

class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self): 
        pass
    def doSomething (self, number) : 
        print number**2

class PPTask (object) :
    def __init__ (self) : 
        pass
    def ppTask(self, number = 1) :
        sum = 0
        sum += number
        tc = TestClass()
        tc.doSomething(sum)
        return sum

if __name__ == '__main__' : 
    job_server = pp.Server()
    job_list = []
    results = []
    for i in xrange(10) : 
        pt = PPTask()
        job_list.append(job_server.submit(pt.ppTask, (1,), globals = globals()))
    for job in job_list : 
        results.append(job())
    for result in results :
        print result
```

This raise `NameError: global name 'TestClass' is not defined` and I didn't find any solution to pass it or reuse it in the ppTask method.

Any help would be greatly appriciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution would be to tell the job server to import the source module itself for each job you submit.  For example, if your script above were called `pptest.py`, you could create the jobs like so:

```
job_list.append(job_server.submit(pt.ppTask, (1,), modules=('pptest',)))
```

And within `ppTask`, you could instantiate `TestClass` like so:

```
tc = pptest.TestClass()
```

So overall, the code would look like this:

```
import pp

class TestClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def doSomething (self, number) :
        print number**2

class PPTask (object) :
    def __init__ (self) :
        pass
    def ppTask(self, number = 1) :
        sum = 0
        sum += number
        tc = pptest.TestClass()
        tc.doSomething(sum)
        return sum

if __name__ == '__main__' :
    job_server = pp.Server()
    job_list = []
    results = []
    for i in xrange(10) :
        pt = PPTask()
        job_list.append(job_server.submit(pt.ppTask, (1,), modules=('pptest',)))
    for job in job_list :
        results.append(job())
    for result in results :
        print result
```

Comment: Thank you, it works well. I still don't understand how globals is handle by th submit method of PP. I did try to pass the TestClass in a dictionnary via globals = {'TestClass': <class '__main__.TestClass'>} and I can't figure out why this doesn't works too.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that too, but couldn't get that to work either.  It seems like it _should_, but I don't know enough about `pp` to say that confidently.  I had never run into this before because I usually put separate classes in separate module files, and just use the `modules` keyword argument to `Server.submit()` to tell the job what to import.